# Meaning of かって?

Tags: grammar

> 胃に穴でも開けるんじゃない**かって**、見てるこっちが心配になった。

I see the point, but this **かって** confusing me. And **んじゃない** don't mean negative sense, right? And I guess that **胃に穴でも開ける** mean "Shit a brick" but I can be wrong. So, what **かって** mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

かって is not a word or phrase so it does not mean anything by itself.

～～かって is a colloquial pronunciation of ～～かと.  The か is a question particle and と is a quoting particle.

[胃]{い}に[穴]{あな}でも[開]{あ}けるんじゃないかって ＝ 『胃に穴でも開けるんじゃないか？』と（思って）

＝ "I thought/wondered to myself (that someone might) 『胃に穴でも開けるんじゃないか？』"

As you said, じゃない here is affirmative.

こっち here means "I" (= the speaker).